# Passing data from database to view correctly

Tags: image, laravel, view

I am creating a simple crud application with file upload. But i have problems in displaying the thumbnail in view(index.blade.php). All images in database are displayed in each book instead of displaying one image in one book. Here is my controller.

```html
   public function index()
   {

 
        $books=UploadedFile::all();
        $files=Upload::all();

        return view('books.index',compact('books','files'));
   }
```

and my index.blade.php

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
         <tr class="bg-info">
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>ISBN</th>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Author</th>
             <th>Publisher</th>
             <th>Thumbs</th>
             <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
       
         @foreach ($books as $book )
             <tr>
                 <td>{{ $book->id }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->isbn }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->author }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $book->publisher }}</td>

                 <td>
                    @foreach ($files as $file )
                        <img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$file->filename)}}" height="40" width="50">
                    @endforeach
                    
                </td>
                 <td><a href="{{url('books',$book->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{{route('books.edit',$book->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a></td>
                 <td>
                 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['books.destroy', $book->id]]) !!}
                 {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                 {!! Form::close() !!}
                 </td>
             </tr>
         @endforeach

         </tbody>

    </table>
```

I separated the table for the filename from the rest of the fields. and here is the result--

Comment: Your post appears incomplete. Where is the result?

Comment: the result is .. in the thumbnail part, there are three pictures shown in each entries because I have 3 pictures in my database

Comment: @WicherVisser is there a way to array the data in controller and call its variable in the foreach?

Comment: I can't see the relation your models. Is there any relationships between UploadedFile and Upload models?

Comment: They are different from each other. UploadedFile is the model for isbn,title,author,publisher. Upload is for the image.